# For a list comprehension in Haskell the equivalent in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm reading the Haskell book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!". Chapter 2 explains list comprehension with this little example:

```
boomBangs xs = [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs, odd x]
```

Can somebody re-written this list comprehension in Scala, please? Scala has no even or odd function? So i must use

```
x%2!=0
```

for check if the number odd?

Thanks in advance for an elegant solution!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even if Scala has no `even` or `odd` function in its standard library (which I am unsure of), it is trivial to implement either. Assuming this (to keep it closest to the original Haskell version), the Scala code may look like

```
val boomBangs = for {
  x <- xs
  if odd x
} yield if (x < 10) "BOOM!" else "BANG!"
```

Disclaimer: I couldn't compile or test it for the time being, so no guarantees that it works as is.

Comment: it even works as is, except for a couple of parentheses: `odd(x)`

Comment: I would write this like the haskell oneliner above: `val boomBangs = for (x <- xs; if odd x) yield if (x < 10) "BOOM!" else "BANG!"`

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to for-comprehensions, here is a solution based on `filter` and `map`:

```
def odd(x: Int) = x % 2 == 1

def boomBangs(xs: Seq[Int]) =
  xs filter odd map {i => if (i < 10) "BOOM!" else "BANG!"}

boomBangs(3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 10 :: 11 :: 12 :: 13 :: Nil)
  // List(BOOM!, BOOM!, BANG!, BANG!)
```

For-comprehensions actually get translated into `withFilter`, `map` and `flatMap` expressions by the compiler.